# «Снести с лица земного шара» — грамотна ли фраза?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

Утренняя программа "Вести" (27.10.2017), диктор:

*Россия испытала ракету, способную снести страну с лица земного шара.*

***Снести с лица земного шара*** — грамотно ли ТАК говорить?

Answer (score 1):

А почему нет? Грамотно будет Снести одним махом пол-лица и  Снести нос и подбородок с лица кого-то? Вполне, а здесь метафора "лицо земного шара", с него тоже можно снести какой-то объект, т.е. мгновенно уничтожить, как бы его и не было.

Comment: Выражение странно тем, что переводит устоявшуюся идиому (которая фигурирует и в переводе Библии) в астрономический аспект "Земли", и такая буквализированная трёхмерность наводит на мысль: может, у земного шара не только "лицо", а и затылок найдётся? Чем-то напоминает даже знаменитую "вот где порывшуюся собаку". https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%BE_%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B8

Comment: «Буквализированная трёхмерность» усилена и странной конкретикой: почему Великобританию, а не «такую страну, как...»

Comment: Это был перевод слов какого-то английского политика. Естественно, он говорил о _своей_ стране. Чтобы никого не смущать, я могу убрать UK из вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Откровенно говоря, я сам удивлен тому, что выражение "стереть с лица земного шара" активно используется, но факты – упрямая вещь. Вот примеры:

Я вернулся к Алпатову с его Золотой луговиной, представил себе, что он, готовый спустить озеро, открывает этот реликт и вдруг останавливается перед вопросом: имеет ли право он, инженер, понимающий лишь техническую сторону дела, **стереть с лица земного шара** этот реликт с его неведомым мифом? ([Михаил Михайлович Пришвин](https://unotices.com/book.php?id=155160&page=16))

Мистер Небль, заслуженный профессор геологии в филадельфийском университете, считающийся в Америке одним из серьезнейших ученых, напечатал в солидном «American-Geological Journal» статью, в которой, доказывает, что в 1972 году Европа будет совершенно **стерта с лица земного шара**. [Очередное светопреставление (1913.09.04) // «Раннее утро», 1913] (Нацкорпус)

"Снести с лица земли" тоже встречается:

Когда появился Мольер, дело разъяснилось вполне: Ратабон явился с великолепным и полностью разработанным проектом перестройки Лувра, причем для успешного хода этой перестройки было необходимо **снести с лица земли** не только Малый Бурбон, но и прилегающую к нему церковь Сен-Женевьев д'Оксерруа. [М. А. Булгаков. Жизнь господина де Мольера (1933)] (Нацкопрус)

Составители текста "творчески" объединили "снести" и "с лица земного шара". Думаю, заменяя "стереть" на "снести", они хотели усилить впечатление, производимое этим сообщением на телезрителей.

Comment: Я тоже хотела внести метку "фразеология", но меня остановило то, что фразеологизм "стереть с лица земли" есть, а фразеологизма "снести с лица земного шара" нет. Поэтому и задала этот вопрос.